# How to create a function in jquery executed right after a grid is loaded

Tags: jquery, gridview

I have one simple gridview, I want to create a function in jquery that is executed right after a grid is loaded.

I'm trying to call with: live and ready, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: You'll need to provide some code if you want any response that actually helps you.

Comment: Why don'y you call the RegisterClientScript block to  call the jquery once the Grid is dataBound..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
$("#grid_view_id").load()
```